# dpkg throws an error when regenerating certs of my instance on AWS

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, docker-machine

I'm trying to regenerate certs for my instance on AWS through Docker-Machine as I do need to do it quite often for some reason. All of the sudden I'm getting this error after running `docker-machine regenerate-certs [instance]`:

```
Error running "DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive sudo -E apt-get install -y  curl": ssh command error:
command : DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive sudo -E apt-get install -y  curl
err     : exit status 100
output  : E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Executing `sudo dpkg --configure -a` won't make the problem go away.

Why I'm getting this all of the sudden and how can I troubleshoot it ?

Answer (score 0):

Since this error was originating from a Docker container on AWS I decided to stop the container and throw it away and create new one. It's not really a solution but I can carry on working now.

Conclusion:  dpkg module got corrupted in the deployed container, not on local machine. Recreated new container.